# Import de dados

Tags: r

Estou tentando importar uma tabela com valores de datetime no r, e os valores não são importados. A coluna com os valores aparece com NA e o seguinte erro é reportado.

```
Parsed with column specification:
    cols(
    HTV = col_time(format = "")
    )
Warning: 15 parsing failures.
row col   expected   actual
   1 HTV valid date 46:57:00
   2 HTV valid date 42:12:00
   3 HTV valid date 67:25:00
   4 HTV valid date 62:53:00
   5 HTV valid date 27:50:00
```

Comment: Esta pergunta está muito genérica. Por favor, compartilhe o código utilizado para importar os dados e as primeiras linhas da tabela a ser importada, caso ela esteja em um arquivo texto, para que possamos ter alguma ideia de como te ajudar.

Comment: Eu votei para fechar esta pergunta uma vez que sem um exemplo mínimo reproduzível será muito difícil que seja respondida corretamente. Denis, caso ela seja fechada, você pode editá-la adicionando o exemplo e reabriremos.